# Does Haven reduce damage of direct hit from AoE weapons?

Tags: paladins

In Paladins there are mainly two defensive items to reduce the damage:

**Haven :** *Reduce the Damage you take from Direct attacks by 10% / 20% / 30%*
**Blast Shield** : *Reduce the Damage you take from Area of Effect attacks by 10% / 20% / 30%*

There are obviously direct damage weapons (like Viktor's weapon) and AoE weapons (like Evie's).

Does **Haven** reduce the damage if I am directly shot by an AoE weapon ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Paladins/comments/57jfne/haven_or_blast_shield_to_clarify_any_confusion/) which tried to clarify this exact question, it seems that Haven **won't** reduce the damages of an AoE weapon like Evie's or Drogoz's:

> Haven protects against all direct damage. Obvious things like kinessas rifle, victor rifle, Makao gun and hook, kinessa arrow, etc.
>
> Blast Shield protects against any AOE damage at all. This includes direct hits from AOE shots and abilities. Drogoz rockets, Evie missiles, Pip flasks, even being stuck by Bomb Kings bombs.. this is all negated by blast shield. **Haven will do nothing here**. A few more things to consider worth mentioning: Victor grenade, Cassie's blast shot, Androxus's ult, and many others are also effected by Blast Shield.

Someone in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=atfHCitdUk0) also tested it with Evie and it shows that a direct hit is not reduced by Haven.

If you want an exact list of which capacities' damages can be reduced by Haven or Blast Shield, you can consult this picture, extracted from [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Paladins/comments/5b822t/paladins_damage_types_per_character/):

[image]

Comment: that clarifies a lot, and the picture is a great tool ! Can you please link where this picture come from ?

Comment: I got it from [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Paladins/comments/5b822t/paladins_damage_types_per_character/). I'll edit the answer to include the source.